# Disallow non-local storage of an object

Tags: design-patterns, c++

I need to write a class in C++ that acquires a hardware resource and releases it again when it is destroyed. Basically that can be done in the constructor and destructor of the class. The difficulty I'm having is that I want this class to be usable as a local object only.

So basically:

```
struct Magic
{
  Magic(const Settings& settings)
  {
    acquireHardware(settings);
  }
  ~Magic()
  {
    releaseHardware();
  }
  // Magic does not need to store the settings or a reference to them
};
```

This should be allowed:

```
void useAllTheHardware(const Settings& settings)
{
  Magic useHardwareWith(settings);
  ...
  // destructor releases the hardware
}
```

This should fail:

```
struct badIdea
{
  badIdea(const Settings& settings)
    : settings_(settings),
    useHardwareWith_(settings)
  {
  }
  Settings settings_;
  Magic useHardwareWith_;
};
badIdea mustFail(settings); // <-- not allowed
```

My environment is exception-free (embedded, and compiled with gcc -fno-exceptions), and if things go terribly wrong there's usually no way of handling that except fixing the bug that caused the crash.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm curious what the motivation for only allowing one "local" instance is. Are you trying to prevent multiple references to the underlying hardware?

Comment: What counts as "local"?  If I create an object in `main` in the outermost scope, it's no different from having a static variable ...

Comment: @StevenBurnap I'm trying to prevent overlapped `acquire()` and `release()` pairs. The hardware driver used is quite simple and provides those methods as a means of synchronizing higher-level access, especially when those higher-level drivers use an interrupt service routine to `acquire()`.

Comment: @Rufflewind indeed, that's correct. As you can see in my answer below, my whole view of my task ("create a class") was misleading my attempt at trying to come up with a solution.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: I am honestly not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but have you looked at overriding `Magic::operator new()` to fail or return a null pointer to fail fast?

Answer (score 1):

You can't *quite* do it, but you can come close:

```
#include <cstddef>

#include <new>

struct Magic
{
    enum promise
    {
        i_promise_not_to_put_this_in_another_class
    };

    void *operator new(size_t) = delete;
    void *operator new[](size_t) = delete;
    void operator delete(void *) = delete;
    void operator delete[](void *) = delete;

    Magic(promise) {}
    Magic(Magic&&) = delete;
    Magic(const Magic&) = delete;
    Magic& operator = (Magic&&) = delete;
    Magic& operator = (const Magic&) = delete;
    ~Magic() {}
};

struct WhyIsThisABadIdea
{
    Magic m;

    WhyIsThisABadIdea() : m(Magic::i_promise_not_to_put_this_in_another_class) {} // obvious lies
};

int main()
{
    Magic m(Magic::i_promise_not_to_put_this_in_another_class); // okay
    //new Magic(Magic::i_promise_not_to_put_this_in_another_class); // error
    WhyIsThisABadIdea bad; // okay
}
```

Comment: I've thought about deleting a number of operators, just as you suggested, but the `BadIdea` kind of structs can always get in the way, just like you demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like answering my own question here, especially because I realized that I asked the wrong question. I was too much focused on OO terms and habits, but the reality is that what I wanted was a *prodedure*, not a class or anything that can actually store a state. Sorry for that.

Here's my (not quite working) solution (improved solution below):

I remembered that there are macros that manage "atomic blocks" by clearing an interrupt enable flag when the block is entered, and restoring it after the block was run. I had a look at those and they are basically just a `for` loop.

Together with an anonymous struct definition in the for loop initialization (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255852) this grew to a solution that works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Settings
{
    Settings(int v_) : v(v_) {}
    int v;
};

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255852
#define useHardwareWith(settings)                   \
acquireHardware(settings);                          \
for(                                                \
  struct                                            \
  {                                                 \
    bool done()                                     \
    {                                               \
      return done_;                                 \
    }                                               \
    bool run()                                      \
    {                                               \
      releaseHardware();                            \
      done_ = true;                                 \
    }                                               \
    bool done_;                                     \
  } magic = {false}; !magic.done() ; magic.run())

void acquireHardware(const Settings& settings)
{
  std::cout << "acquire(" << settings.v << ")\n";
}

void releaseHardware()
{
  std::cout << "release()\n";
}

int main()
{
  Settings settings(1);
  useHardwareWith(settings)
  {
    std::cout << "Doing important hardware stuff\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
acquire(1)
Doing important hardware stuff
release()
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/eT91hD

The `for` macro cannot be stored, so it's not *disallowing non-local storage*, but simply doing something in a specific order.

---

### This is better

Above solution has a major problem: `release()` is not called when `break` or `return` is called in the loop, because `release()` is in the "increment" part, and not in a destructor. Unfortunately, a destructor for the anonymous cannot be defined. So I added a named inner struct to do that:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Settings
{
    Settings(int v_) : v(v_) {}
    int v;
};

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255852
#define useHardwareWith(settings)                   \
acquireHardware(settings);                          \
for(                                                \
  struct                                            \
  {                                                 \
    struct inner                                    \
    {                                               \
      inner() : done_(false)                        \
      {                                             \
      }                                             \
      ~inner()                                      \
      {                                             \
        releaseHardware();                          \
      }                                             \
      bool done_;                                   \
    };                                              \
    bool done() const                               \
    {                                               \
      return inner_.done_;                          \
    }                                               \
    bool run()                                      \
    {                                               \
      inner_.done_ = true;                          \
    }                                               \
    inner inner_;                                   \
  } magic; !magic.done() ; magic.run())

void acquireHardware(const Settings& settings)
{
  std::cout << "acquire(" << settings.v << ")\n";
}

void releaseHardware()
{
  std::cout << "release()\n";
}

void doHardwareStuff(const Settings& settings)
{
  useHardwareWith(settings)
  {
    if (settings.v == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "side-exit\n";
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "Doing important hardware stuff\n";
  }
}

int main()
{
  Settings settings(0);
  doHardwareStuff(settings);
  doHardwareStuff(Settings(1));
}
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/z3Qm8a

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can prevent the creation of objects with static storage duration (e.g. [C++ - Prevent global instantiation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13496027/3235496))

You could run a check **at runtime**:

```
bool ALLOW = false;

struct Magic
{
  // ...

  ~Magic()
  {
    if (!ALLOW)
      std::cerr << "Some diagnostic message\n";
    releaseHardware();
  }
}; 


int main()
{
  ALLOW = true;

  // ...

  ALLOW = false;  // reset before main() ends
  return 0;
}
```

The destructor of variables with static storage duration

- is called after `main()` ends and
- for this reason it will print an error message

Of course this is only a check, but can be quite useful to correct the code.

Consider that it doesn't prevent something like:

```
int main()
{
   Magic useHardwareWith(settings);

   // ...
}
```

Comment: It is possible to create "only local" objects by using an anonymous struct, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11255852 or my selfie-answer. Having a global guard variable (`Allow`) is also not very handy if multiple different resources must be managed.

Comment: The `ALLOW` variable won't prevent the creation of multiple `Magic` objects (it isn't a guard): it's used just to signal if you have created such objects. Your solution is nice and, of course, is a solution ;-) but it seems to me that it doesn't regard the only-local constraint.